# .Net Core System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode not working when the "&" symbol is there

Tags: c#, htmldecode

```
string x = "&Microsoft&lt;?xml version=";
string y = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Now the y value is `&Microsoft&lt;?xml version=`

In this case the web.httputility.htmldecode not working

I am expecting result is `&Microsoft<?xml version=`

Please reply if there is answer for this.

Comment: The input string is in an invalid format/encoding, so it might be tricky to define a correct return value from that method.

Comment: Where is x coming from? It should actually be `&amp;Microsoft…` to be valid as the & character masks the start of a HTML entity and must end with a ; character. Therefore if one wants to have the & itself it must be escaped by using &amp;

Comment: The value is coming from api. That api response is like that.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good. Upon testing it on my local. I got what your expected result.

[image]

**UPDATE**
For .Net Core, it still the same code but rather remove the unnecessary '&' on the first character of the string. Because it is forbidden to use ampersand without any related url encoding version

> `eg: '&lt;' = '<'`

You can check the code behind for .net core implementation of [HtmlEncoder.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/1dfe38aeb2811fbbd6d4de36d210f060e80d50a6/src/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/HtmlEncoder.cs)

I hope it helps. Happy coding.

Comment: are you using System.Web or System.Net?

Comment: I'm using System.Web

Comment: I am using .Net framework version is 4.8.03752.

Visual Studio 2019.

Is there any version difference?

Comment: I'm using .Net Framework v4.7.2 i don't have 4.8 yet.

Comment: Sorry, Now verified. This is working in .Net Framework. But not working in .NetCore. I am using .NetCore Version is 3.1. I updated my question title. Can you verify from you end with .Net Core?

Comment: @Saravanapandian please mark my post as an answer will greatly appreciated. Cheers!